# 200 response status with requests library but 500 with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

When I use make the request with the requests library, it works:

```
import requests


r = requests.get("https://www.opentable.de/c/raum-stuttgart-restaurants")
print r
```

The response is 200:

> Response [200]

But when I try to do the same thing with Scrapy I get 500 response status:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

from opentable.items import OpentableItem


class GermanySpider(Spider):
    name = "germany_spider"

    start_urls = [
                "https://www.opentable.de/c/raum-stuttgart-restaurants"
                ]

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

Log:

```
2017-05-30 23:28:33 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: opentable)
2017-05-30 23:28:33 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2017-05-30 23:28:33 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'opentable.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['op
entable.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'opentable'}
2017-05-30 23:28:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2017-05-30 23:28:38 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAg
entMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMidd
leware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2017-05-30 23:28:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware
, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2017-05-30 23:28:39 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2017-05-30 23:28:39 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-30 23:28:39 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-05-30 23:28:39 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-05-30 23:28:42 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.opentable.de/rest_list.aspx?m=227> (failed 1 times): 500 I
nternal Server Error
2017-05-30 23:28:43 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.opentable.de/rest_list.aspx?m=227> (failed 2 times): 500 I
nternal Server Error
2017-05-30 23:28:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.opentable.de/rest_list.aspx?m=227> (failed 3 times
): 500 Internal Server Error
2017-05-30 23:28:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET https://www.opentable.de/rest_list.aspx?m=227> (referer: None)
2017-05-30 23:28:44 [scrapy] DEBUG: Ignoring response <500 https://www.opentable.de/rest_list.aspx?m=227>: HTTP status c
ode is not handled or not allowed
2017-05-30 23:28:44 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-05-30 23:28:44 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1344,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1837,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/500': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 18, 28, 44, 745000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 6,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 30, 18, 28, 39, 76000)}
2017-05-30 23:28:44 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

At scrapinghub there is the same response.
Why does it happen? What's the difference between a request with requests and a request with Scrapy?

Comment: You're accessing two different URL's - or rather Scrapy is trying to load links from the init page and those links are throwing Error 500.

Comment: What headers do you use? The site may ban requests with scrapy default HTTP header.

Comment: Looks like a User-Agent string thing. Try changing your User-Agent to something like a real desktop browser, or "Mozilla", e.g `USER_AGENT="Mozilla"` in your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem and, after debugging Scrapy requests, I've found it send these headers by default:

> **Accept**:
> text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> **Accept-Encoding**: gzip,deflate

For me it was the **Accept** header that was causing the error 500. After setting it to */* the server returned a 200 response.